# how to grant adb shell permission without rooting devices

Tags: android, adb

I am running following commands from command prompt while running it shows permission denied. can any one please explain how to grant permission?

```
C:\android\tools>adb push asl-native /data/local/asl-native
failed to copy 'asl-native' to '/data/local/asl-native': Permission denied
```

Comment: @dtmilano pushing to sdcard is working,after pushing we have to run that one while running also same message permissio denied

Comment: most devices mount SD cards with noexec option - if that's the case you won't be able to run an app from the card

Comment: This is precisely the reason why adb shell is not granted root access, to avoid loading and executing stuff which is a security risk

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to write to /data unless your phone is rooted and able to run adb shell as root.

Looking at asl's run script you might be able to change it to install it to the scard. I haven't tested it but it would look something like this:

```
# Install service
echo "Installing native service..."
$adb push ./asl-native /sdcard/asl-native
$adb shell /system/bin/chmod 0777 /sdcard/asl-native

# Start the service
echo "Starting service..."
$adb shell "/sdcard/asl-native /sdcard/asl-native.log" &
echo "Service started successfully."
```

Although I dunno if you're allowed to run chmod and make something executable. You might want to try running chmod 0777 on your local machine first.

Comment: while running  this command it displaying premission denied message $adb shell "/sdcard/asl-native /sdcard/asl-native.log" &

Answer (score 1):

Follow the comment of [ankita] (https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/UserGuide):
"It can work for non rooted device also.just change all path /data/local to /data/local/tmp in run.bat file then save and run it."
I tried and the problem were solved

Answer (score 0):

Find a partition on your phone which is both writable (for the `shell` user) and does not have the `noexec` option and push your executable to that partition.